# Cleartool find command within a directory only

Tags: unix, clearcase

I'm using the following command:

```
cleartool find . -all -nvisible -print
```

Its returning information for every file in my /vob

I really want to limit the search to a specific directory, but I can't get the syntax correct.

Ex:

```
cleartool find /vob/dir1/dir2/ -all -nvisible -print
```

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, by looking at the documentation of [`cleartool find`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm):

```
-a/ll
```

> With pname arguments, modifies the meaning of each argument to specify its entire VOB, **not just a single file or directory**.
>   Without any pname arguments, specifies the VOB containing the current working directory.
>
> Note: When you use find -all, only one instance of an element is reported, even if one or more VOB hard links point to the element. Either the element name or one of the VOB hard links is displayed.

Try without the `-all` to see if it still fits your need.

```
cleartool find /vob/dir1/dir2/ -print
```

However, that will only find *visible* elements, `-nvis` is only used with `-all` for a vob-wide search.

Comment: I tried that and it came up with an error stating I had to use -all with the -nvisible flag

Comment: @user432209 correct, I have edited my answer to point out that: looking for non-visible files means vob-wide search.