# How to Find a specific Component in a Project - Clearcase

Tags: bash, unix, clearcase

I want to know How to Find a specific Component in a Project using SCRIPT.
EG:
I imagine something like:   cleartool find -component hello.txt 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to find the UCM component which includes the file `hello.txt`? `hello.txt` is not a component in itself. And what version of ClearCase are you using? What is your OS client? And your OS for the ClearCase server?

Comment: I have a Project in clearcase explorer and I wuold add 4000 elements in diferents VOBs (folders), then I would like to exceute a unix command to find where some "XXX" element is located. (the Clearcase route .../.../.../../xxx.txt)

Answer (score 1):

If those elements are directly visible in the views used to add them, you can use a regular unix-like find command.
That view would be an UCM one referencing an UCM stream with all (vob-based) components in it, set with foundation baselines.

But if you want to search an element in any view (and not just the view used to add them), then a [`cleartool find -all`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16817636/6309) is more appropriate.

Take any UCM view which display any baseline of those same component, and execute in each one of them:

```
cleartool find -all -name "afile.txt" -print
```

Add `-nvis` if you want to find a file that might have been deleted or is not selected by your current view.